# My GWT application is slower when compiled than in Super Dev Mode

Tags: javascript, gwt

I have a problem with my GWT app. It's much slower when I run it compiled than when I run it on "Super Dev Mode on an external Server"; whatever the browser I use.

In the two cases, I run the app on a Tomcat 7.0.59, and the server calls spend nearly the same time.

When I timeline the same action on the two versions of the apps with Chrome, I have the following results :

**Compiled**
 
58.626 ms : Loading
46.69 s : Scripting
198.526 ms : Rendering
1.89 s : Painting
869.991 : Other
4.46 s : Idle

Here is a link to the image of memory : https://drive.google.com/uc?/export=view&id=0B0sVNHNdyBWHWXA4aVJFelozc2M

**Super Dev**
65.706 ms : Loading
15.99 s : Scripting
194.724 : Rendering
1.85 : Painting
827.993 ms : Other
6.65 : Idle

Here is a link to the image of memory : https://drive.google.com/uc?/export=view&id=0B0sVNHNdyBWHNk0yLWxOM3Z6Nlk

There is clearly a problem with the Used JS Heap and the scripting time... But why? Dunno... Am I alone with this problem ? Or did I miss something ?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try to JS profile in Chrome Dev Tools. You will get a flame chart which shows where exactly the time is spent. Also compile and test in draft mode to see if it makes a difference

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying it right now! I'll tell you what happens! But can be a good way because I saw an error when I JS Profiled yesterday that was something like : "Not optimized : too optimized"... Let's see...

Comment: Trying to do it... Doesn't seem to have any change... Maybe, I draft it wrong because in my log during the compilation, I always have : [INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0:compile (default) @ myproject ---  I add this in my POM.xml, under the configuration : <draftCompile>true</draftCompile><optimizationLevel>0</optimizationLevel> ... Not sure if I'm doing it well, because, the compilation pass doesn't looks like the one of the super dev mode... :(

Comment: To make sure just compare the js output of the normal normal compile and the one with draftCompile= true. Alternatively you can also pass `-Dgwt.draftCompile=true` to the `mvn gwt:compile` goal.

Comment: My draft configuration was correct 5000ko vs 9000ko, but the result is still the same... I really don't see... I'll reprofile it... Thanks for your help

Comment: I think that I have found the problem since... But really don't know. Must have been a conf thing. Not doing GWT anymore tho (even if I think it could have been a very very good tool in the end) ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Will close the subject.